# Avoid Browser to cache

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache

Hi I have created a website(for learning) : [Strore Ascii Art-Google AppEngine](http://hungaaama.appspot.com/asciiart)

If a user enters a piece of art it redirects the user to front page and then show the recent most ascii arts.

But it is sometimes showing the arts sometimes not.
Probably because it is being cached.

I am using **google App Engine**

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (both lines needed) in your  section::

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Comment: @Atul, use BOTH lines please

Comment: I tried it too.I think its not the browser its google appengine which is caching it.